# fancy box gallery issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox, gallery

I'd like to have a gallery that opens up from the word GALLERY.

Here's my code --> at the moment the gallery effect is not working. I can just see the first pic in the fancy box. Any help appreciated! thanks.

I am trying to have this effect http://jsfiddle.net/uZCC6/

HTML //

```
<li>

<a class="fancybox" href="images/WTWH/1.jpg">GALLERY</a>

<div class="hidden">
<a class="fancybox" href="images/WTWH/2.jpg"><img src="images/WTWH/2.jpg"></a>
</div>

</li>
```

CSS//

```
.hidden {
display:none;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.fancybox').fancybox();
        });


            $(".fancybox")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        padding : 0
    });

    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers:  {
            thumbs : {
                width: 50,
                height: 50
            }
        }
    });

            $(".various").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 800,
        maxHeight   : 600,
        fitToView   : false,
        width       : '70%',
        height      : '60%',
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
```

Comment: forgot to say that I'm using this: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox

Comment: If you initialize the same selector several times, only the last one will take effect. Use the second only to get what you want and make sure is wrapped inside the `.ready()` method (only the first one is so far)

Comment: thank you! now it's working - I am still studying js.